# Add two dependent select with add button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, database

Im trying to create a button that add/remove a two dependent from with data taken from a database.
This is the select

```
<!-- Products name dropdown -->
<select id="nameProducts">
    <option value="">Select Product</option>
    <?php 
    if(pg_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
        while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo '<option value="'.$row['Prod_ID'].'">'.$row['Nombre_Prod'].'</option>'; 
        }
    }else{ 
        echo '<option value="">Product not available</option>'; 
    } 
    ?>
</select> 

<!-- Quantity dropdown -->
<select id="stock">
    <option value="">Select Quantity</option>
</select>
```

This is the script that update second select:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nameProducts').on('change', function(){
        var Prod_ID = $(this).val();
        if(Prod_ID){
            console.log(Prod_ID)
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'prod_id='+Prod_ID,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#stock').html(html);
                }
            }); 
        }else{
            $('#stock').html('<option value="">Select Product First</option>');
        }
    });     
    
});
</script>
```

Then i was trying to control add/remove those selects with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var maxField = 10; 
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); 
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper');
    var fieldHTML = '   
                        <select id="nameProducts">
                            <option value="">Select Product</option>
                            <?php 
                            if(pg_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
                                while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                    echo '<option value="'.$row['Prod_ID'].'">'.$row['Nombre_Prod'].'</option>'; 
                                }
                            }else{ 
                                echo '<option value="">Product not available</option>'; 
                            } 
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    '; 
    var x = 1;
    
    //Once add button is clicked
    $(addButton).click(function(){
        if(x < maxField){ 
            x++; 
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML); 
        }
    });
    
    //Once remove button is clicked
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--; 
    });
});
</script>
```

and html code for add/remove button:

```
<div class="field_wrapper">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="field_name[]" value=""/>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add field">Add Product</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The problem?**
This is not working. I asumme i cant only paste html code who displays two select into script which control add/remove.
Sorry if you find any spanish var.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing server code and javascript code. This won't work:

```
    var fieldHTML = '   
                    <select id="nameProducts">
                        <option value="">Select Product</option>
                        <?php 
                        if(pg_num_rows($result) > 0){ 
                            while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
                                echo '<option value="'.$row['Prod_ID'].'">'.$row['Nombre_Prod'].'</option>'; 
                            }
                        }else{ 
                            echo '<option value="">Product not available</option>'; 
                        } 
                        ?>
                    </select>
```

PHP is a server language that renders the page and sends it to client (the browser), including any javascript.
When the browser reads the rendered answer from the server, it will execute any javascript code if present.
You're trying to run php commands in the browser. You have to think of another aproach to that.

You can for example, make php generate a list, and hide it in a non-visible element. Then js can copy values and unhide things, but it won't run php code.

Better still you can make an ajax call to the server and render the option elements based on the server's answer.